# HTTP request to AWS with okhttp

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, okhttp, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I'm pretty new to AWS and I'd like to use a service in my Android app. Unfortunately, this service, AWS AppConfig, doesn't have a mobile SDK yet, so I've been trying to send a GET request to the [GetConfiguration API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/2019-10-09/APIReference/API_GetConfiguration.html#API_GetConfiguration_RequestSyntax) with okhttp.

To sign the [request](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference/com/amazonaws/DefaultRequest.html), I'm using [AWS4Signer](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference/com/amazonaws/auth/AWS4Signer.html) from the AWS Android SDK. I'm providing credentials with an implementation of [AWSCredentials](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials.html).

```
    com.amazonaws.Request requestAws = new DefaultRequest(amazonWebServiceRequest, serviceName);
    URI uri = URI.create("https://appconfig.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/applications/[applicationID]/environments/[environmentID]/configurations/[configurationID]?client_id=ClientId");
    requestAws.setEndpoint(uri);
    requestAws.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.GET);
    AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
    signer.setServiceName(serviceName);
    signer.setRegionName(Regions.US_WEST_2.getName());
    signer.sign(requestAws, credentials);
    // get relevant authorization headers from requestAws and insert them in the okhttp request as headers
```

When I send a request to GetConfiguration, it fails with

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```

I tried sending a request to [GetDeploymentStrategy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/2019-10-09/APIReference/API_GetDeploymentStrategy.html), and that was successful, so I don't think it's my credentials or how I'm attaching them to the request.

I think the problem is with how I'm attaching the request parameters, since the APIs that don't require additional request params succeed (GetDeploymentStrategy and GetApplication), while GetConfiguration, which requires `client_id`, fails.

My question is: are there any examples of how to handle request parameters with the signer and request?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent some more time trying different things and I have something that works. Query parameters need to be attached using com.amazonaws.Request's [setParameters](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference/com/amazonaws/Request.html#setParameters-java.util.Map-) method. I did the same for the resource path and [setResourcePath](https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference/com/amazonaws/Request.html#setResourcePath-java.lang.String-).

Example for creating the request to be signed:

```
private static String endpoint = "https://appconfig.us-west-2.amazonaws.com";
private static String resourcePath = "/applications/[applicationID]/environments/[environmentID]/configurations/[configurationID]";
private static String parameters = "?client_id=hello&client_configuration_version=0";
private static String fullUrl = endpoint + resourcePath + parameters;
private static String serviceName = "appconfig";

private com.amazonaws.Request createAwsRequest() {
    AmazonWebServiceRequest amazonWebServiceRequest = new AmazonWebServiceRequest() {
    };

    com.amazonaws.Request requestAws = new DefaultRequest(amazonWebServiceRequest, serviceName);

    URI uri = URI.create(endpoint);
    requestAws.setEndpoint(uri);
    requestAws.setResourcePath(resourcePath);
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("client_id", "hello");
    params.put("client_configuration_version", "0");
    requestAws.setParameters(params);
    requestAws.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.GET);

    return requestAws;
}
```